# How can I list multiple schools under education on the timeline in Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

How can I control what school appears on the timeline in the Intro section? 
Currently I have only the latest school showing up. How can I make the previous one visible in the Intro section? I have the privacy set to Public for both, but still, on the timeline only the most recent one is visible.

Answer (score 1):

See this [How to update the work and education section of my About page](https://www.facebook.com/help/353111348061173). It says:

> If you're seeing an issue when you try to update the work and education section of your profile, you may want to try making the updates from another computer or browser. If the issue continues to occur, you can also try disabling any third-party add-ons or extensions you use with your browser.
>
> If neither of these suggestions resolve the issue, please use [this form](https://www.facebook.com/help/186570224871049) to let us know more.